# Оптимизация кода функции, делающей табуляцию в строке char, С

Tags: c, оптимизация

Функция добавляет табуляцию, определяемую параметром `pad` функции.
Проблемы:

1. Первая проблема заключается в том, что, когда я пытаюсь освободить в `main` массив, который возвращает эта функция, у меня возникает ошибка. В режиме отладки я получаю следующее сообщение:

   > Получен сигнал: SIGABRT (Aborted)
   >   Для программы main, PID 8 688.
   >   Можно игнорировать сигнал или переслать его, либо продолжить или приостановить процесс

Также в строке `by 0x402509: test_indent (test_source.c:178)` tests in `test_intend` `valgrind`-а тесты освобождают память, поэтому это одна и та же проблема.

2. Вторая проблема видна из `Valgrind`: ему не нравятся `malloc` и `strncpy`. Использование `memcpy` вместо `strncpy` ничего не меняет. После каждого упоминания `intend` в `Valgrind` я добавил строку, в которой ему что-то не нравится.

Это задание - часть курсов языка С и когда я отправляю код на сервер, там проверяются утечки памяти и др. с помощью `Valgrind`. Когда я пытаюсь отправить конкретно эту функцию на сервер, получаю сообщение об неудаче "Early exit with return value 1". Также хотелось бы знать, что за `host stacktrace` с множеством вопросительных знаков?

Буду рад любой помощи!

```
//------------- Valgrind validations ------------------
==396== Invalid write of size 1
==396==    at 0x4C2C884: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401E7C: indent (polisher.c:116)  
c:116      strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);   
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  Address 0x59122c0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 144 alloc'd 
==396==    at 0x4C2AD10: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401D2B: indent (polisher.c:80)
c:80       dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  
==396== Invalid write of size 1 
==396==    at 0x401EF4: indent (polisher.c:127)
c:127      dest[dest_offset++] = c;      
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  Address 0x59122c0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 144 alloc'd 
==396==    at 0x4C2AD10: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401D2B: indent (polisher.c:80)
c:80       dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  
==396== Invalid write of size 1 
==396==    at 0x401E45: indent (polisher.c:112)
c:112      dest[dest_offset++] = c;
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  Address 0x59122cb is 11 bytes after a block of size 144 alloc'd 
==396==    at 0x4C2AD10: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401D2B: indent (polisher.c:80)    
c:80       dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  
==396== Invalid write of size 1 
==396==    at 0x4C2C7FC: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401E7C: indent (polisher.c:116)
c:116      strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==  Address 0x59122cc is 12 bytes after a block of size 144 alloc'd 
==396==    at 0x4C2AD10: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401D2B: indent (polisher.c:80) 
c:80       dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235) 
==396==

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:304 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed. 
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 208, hi = 2461329846612619888. 
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the 
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any 
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will 
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.   


host stacktrace: 
==396==    at 0x380A48EF: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x380A49E4: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x380A4B66: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x380B170D: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x3809DC93: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x3809C73B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x380A05BA: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x3809BCB2: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x808D20101: ??? 
==396==    by 0x808B95EEF: ??? 
==396==    by 0x38072A6F: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux) 
==396==    by 0x401E7C: indent (polisher.c:116)  

sched status:   
running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable 
==396==    at 0x4C2C7FC: __strncpy_sse2_unaligned (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so) 
==396==    by 0x401EBE: indent (polisher.c:122) 
c:122      strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);
==396==    by 0x402556: test_indent (test_source.c:178) 
==396==    by 0x406B07: srunner_run (in /tmc/test/test) 
==396==    by 0x402BA9: tmc_run_tests (tmc-check.c:134) 
==396==    by 0x402844: main (test_source.c:235)   

Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution. 
It contains workarounds to several common problems. 
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after 
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance 
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or 
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.  

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org  

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind 
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

=========================================================================

```
/* Indent the C-code at memory block <indent>. String <pad> represents
 * one block of indentation. Only opening curly braces '{' increase the
 * indentation level, and closing curly braces '}' decrease the indentation level.
 * Return the pointer to the code after modification.
 * Calling code is responsible of freeing only the memory block returned by
 * the function.
 */
char *indent(char *input, const char *pad)
{
    size_t pad_len = strlen(pad);
    size_t pad_level = 0;
    char *dest;
    if(!input)
        return NULL;
    size_t dest_len = strlen(input);
    size_t dest_offset = 0;
    char c;
    dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));
    if(!dest)
        return NULL;
    while(isspace(*input))
        input++;
    while(*input)
    {
         c = *input;
        if(c == '{')
            pad_level++; 
        if(c == '}')
            pad_level--;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            while(isspace(*input))
                input++;
            if(!*input)
            {
                dest[dest_offset++] = c; 
                break;
            }
            if((pad_len * pad_level) > (dest_len - dest_offset)) 
            {
                char *ptr = realloc(dest, dest_len * 2);
                if(!ptr) 
                {
                    free(dest);
                    return NULL;
                }
                dest_len *= 2;
                dest = ptr;                 
            }
            dest[dest_offset++] = c;
            if(*input != '}')
                for(unsigned int q = 1; q <= pad_level; q++)
                {
                    strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);
                    dest_offset += pad_len;
                }
            else
                for(unsigned int q = 1; q <= pad_level - 1; q++)
                {
                    strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);
                    dest_offset += pad_len;
                }              
            continue;
        } 
        dest[dest_offset++] = c;        
        input++;
    }
    dest[dest_offset] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. `realloc` — операция выделения дополнительной области памяти.

   Сами операции выделения памяти достаточно ресурсоёмки. Как я вижу в коде это все делается еще в цикле... Если от этого попробовать уйти (один раз выделить большой кусок памяти), то производительность повысится.
2. Вроде код дублируется. Я бы вынес его в отдельные функции и вызывал их.
3. Могу ошибаться, но доступ по индексу медленнее, чем доступ к элементу через смещение.
4. Еще можно попробовать распараллелить процесс. Каждый поток берет свое множество строк и работает с ним.

Скорее всего будет достаточно поправить первый пункт.

Comment: Третий пункт - действительно ошибаетесь. индекс в массиве - то же смещение. у процессора просто не существует других способов доступа

Comment: @Mike отредактировал - проблемы всё равно остались.

Answer (score 1):

Я б даже не пытался разобраться в настолько навороченном чужом исходнике. Задача же довольно простая, кто мешает самому написать так как понятно и удобно именно тебе?

Вот что набросалось буквально на коленке. Код не идеален, конечно. Из явных недостатков - не проверяется вхождение `}` и `{` в строки, и доводить до ума есть что. Но явно же наглядней:

```
char *indent( const char *src, const char *pad )
{
    size_t pad_len = strlen( pad );
    size_t pad_level = 0;
    char *dest;
    size_t dest_len = strlen( src );
    size_t dest_offset = 0;
    char c;
    size_t i;
    /* Плохая, очень плохая, очень-очень-очень плохая идея -
     * раскурочивать исходную строку.
     * Лучше выделим отдельную память для результата:
     */
    dest = malloc( dest_len + 1 );

    if( !dest ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    while( isspace( *src ) ) {
        src++;
    }

    while( *src ) {
        c = *src;

        if( c == '\n' ) {
            while( isspace( *src ) ) {
                src++;
            }

            if( !*src ) {
                break;
            }

            /* Проверяем размер строки-приёмника только здесь.
             * В других местах смысла нет, мы заранее заложились
             * на длину исходной строки как минимум.
             */
            if( ( pad_len * pad_level ) > ( dest_len - dest_offset ) ) {
                /* Увеличиваем строку-приёмник в 2 раза. Некоторые
                 * источники рекомендуют в полтора раза. Ну а если
                 * совсем с памятью туго, можно и на величину
                 * (pad_len*pad_level), или просто на какую-то
                 * фиксированную величину. Только скорости это уж точно
                 * не добавит.
                 */
                char *ptr = realloc( dest, dest_len * 2 );

                if( !ptr ) {
                    free( dest );
                    return NULL;
                }

                dest_len *= 2;
                dest = ptr;
            }

            dest[dest_offset++] = c;

            if( *src == '}' ) {
                if( pad_level ) {
                    pad_level--;
                }
                else {
                    /* обработать ошибку: закрывающая скобка не на месте */
                }
            }

            for( i = 0; i < pad_level; i++ ) {
                memcpy( dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len );
                dest_offset += pad_len;
            }

            continue;
        }

        /* Здесь я немного не понял, скобки в любом месте влияют на
         * уровень отступов, или только если они встречаются в начале
         * строки. Для примера и так сойдёт.
         */
        if( c == '}' ) {
            if( pad_level ) {
                pad_level--;
            }
            else {
                /* обработать ошибку: закрывающая скобка не на месте */
            }
        }
        else if( c == '{' ) {
            pad_level++;
        }

        dest[dest_offset++] = c;
        src++;
    }

    dest[dest_offset] = 0;
    return dest;
}
```

**P.S.** Кстати, для ответов на вопросы уровня "в каком месте тормозит и что оптимизтровать" специально придумали отдельный класс программ. Называются "профайлеры" и должны быть в арсенале любого сишника наряду с компилятором, линкером и отладчиком.

Comment: отредактировал - проблемы всё равно остались.

Comment: Не устраивают почему-то строки `strncpy(dest + dest_offset, pad, pad_len + 1);`, `dest = calloc(strlen(input) + 1, sizeof(char));`, `dest[dest_offset++] = c;`.

Comment: Первое же, что бросается в глаза: вы зачем-то копируете `pad_len+1` байт вместо `pad_len`. Скорее всего тут-то и запарывается память, по лишнему байту на каждый уровень `pad_level`.

Comment: уже исправил - всё равно

Comment: Тогда приводите набор входных данных. У меня valgrind ничего не ловит.

Comment: В смысле? Как это сделать?

Comment: @ВадзімКудрэвіч, вот ещё потенциальный глюк: `realloc(dest, dest_len * 2);` (надо бы единичку добавить, `(dest_len * 2) + 1`